# std::make_pair type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl

I came across some odd thing I would like to have an explanation for. The following code snippet provides a simple class template `type` and two `operator<<`s: one for specializations of `type` and one for a `std::pair` of `type` specializations.

```cpp
#include <ostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class type {

public:

  T value_;

};

template <typename CTy, typename CTr, typename T>
std::basic_ostream<CTy,CTr>&
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CTy,CTr>& os, type<T> const& a)
{
  return os << a.value_;
}

template <typename CTy, typename CTr, typename T>
std::basic_ostream<CTy,CTr>&
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CTy,CTr>& os, std::pair<T const, T const> const& a)
{
  return os << a.first << ',' << a.second;
}

#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
  using float_type = type<float>;

  float_type const a = { 3.14159 };
  float_type const b = { 2.71828 };

#if 0
  std::cout << std::make_pair(a, b)
            << std::endl;
#else
  std::cout << std::pair<float_type const, float_type const>(a, b)
            << std::endl;
#endif
}
```

The `main` function provides a specialization and two variables of that specialization. There are two variants for displaying the variables as a `std::pair`. The first fails because `std::make_pair` seems to strip the `const` specifier from the variables, which in turn doesn't match with the signature of the second `operator<<`: `std::pair<T const, T const>`. However, constructing a `std::pair` specialization (second `std::cout` line in `main`) works as well as removing the `const` specification for `T` from `operator<<` for `std::pair`, i.e. `std::pair<T, T>`.

Compiler messages::

- gcc 4.9.2

  ```
  std_make_pair.cpp: In function 'int main()':
  std_make_pair.cpp:52:35: error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
     std::cout << std::make_pair(a, b) << std::endl;
                                 ^
  In file included from std_make_pair.cpp:3:0:
  /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/ostream:602:5: note: initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = std::pair<type<float>, type<float> >]'
   operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
   ^
  ```
- clang 3.5 (non-viable functions from system headers removed)

  ```
  std_make_pair.cpp:52:13: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>')
    and 'pair<typename __decay_and_strip<const type<float> &>::__type, typename __decay_and_strip<const
    type<float> &>::__type>')
    std::cout << std::make_pair(a, b) << std::endl;
    ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  std_make_pair.cpp:30:1: note: candidate template ignored: can't deduce a type for 'T' which would make
    'const T' equal 'type<float>'
  operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CTy,CTr>& os, std::pair<T const, T const> const& a)
  ```

so, here's the question: am I supposed to specify an `operator<<` taking a `std::pair` of `T` instead of `T const`? Isn't that watering down the contract I'm setting up with any user of the functionality, i.e. with `T const` I basically promise to use `T` only in non-mutating ways?

Comment: I consider std::pair and std::make_pair no good (especially with std::map, where std::make_pair(key, value) is not providing the map::value_type).

Comment: @marco-a thanks for editing the compiler messages. the doc wasn't very clear how to do that. did you use a `<!-- language: ... -->` tag?

Comment: @regnirpsj nope, when there's a bullet list twice the number of code spaces are needed. It should be stated somewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The first fails because `std::make_pair` seems to strip the const specifier from the variables, which in turn doesn't match with the signature of the second `operator<<: std::pair<T const, T const>`

That is correct. `make_pair` is a function template that relies on [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) to explicitly drop `const`, `volatile`, and `&` qualifiers:

> ```
> template <class T1, class T2>
>   constexpr pair<V1, V2> make_pair(T1&& x, T2&& y);
> ```
>
> Returns: `pair<V1, V2>(std::forward<T1>(x), std::forward<T2>(y));`
>   where `V1` and `V2` are determined as follows: Let `Ui` be `decay_t<Ti>` for each `Ti`. Then each `Vi` is `X&` if `Ui` equals `reference_wrapper<X>`, otherwise `Vi` is `Ui`.

The compiler is completely correct to reject your code - you added a stream operator for `pair<const T, const T>`, but are trying to stream a `pair<T, T>`. The solution is to just remove the extra `const` requirement in your stream operator. Nothing in that function requires that the `pair` consist of `const` types - just that the types themselves are streamable, which is independent of their `const`ness. There is nothing wrong with this:

```
template <typename CTy, typename CTr, typename T>
std::basic_ostream<CTy,CTr>&
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CTy,CTr>& os, std::pair<T, T> const& a)
{
  return os << a.first << ',' << a.second;
}
```

You're *already* taking the `pair` by reference-to-const, it's not like you can modify its contents anyway.

Comment: Yep. The library is trying to stop you from getting into a `const` mess; make the pair `const`, not its elements.

Comment: `std::pair` has two members for which `const`ness depends on the template parameter and not so much on the run-time `const`ness of the `std::pair` itself. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @regnirpsj Consider that you cannot modify an `int const&` even though `int` is mutable.

Comment: @Barry mmh, `int const&` actually says `reference to constant int`, which clearly forbids mutating `int`. otoh, `int* const` is a `constant pointer to int`, so `int` is mutable, just the pointer to it cannot be changed. however, i take your point(s) and may have to file a defect report w/ the language lawyers ;)

Comment: @regnirpsj Huh? Defect report for *what*?

Comment: @Barry Guess Maybe I had not enough sleep :) I see that `std::pair<T,T>` and `std::pair<T const, T const>` are two distinct types and that for the latter access to `first`/`second` is read-only if the `std::pair<>` instance is already `const`. that would also explain the decision in the standard to have `std::make_pair<>` strip all qualifiers. maybe I was a bit overzealous in providing non-mutating contracts w/o realizing that `const` on the `std::pair<>` instance also extends to its members. so, no defect report required ;)